# On focusing number box (input type="number"), the defaultValue(0) should be cleared out and it should be blank in Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, input

Please help me in clearing the number box. Thanks in advance.

````
    const [number,SetNumber] = useState(0)
    const handleFocus = (event) => {
       //If it is text box setNumber("")
       //for number box, how to clear?
    }
    return (
        <div>
            <form>
                <input type="number" onFocus={handleFocus} value={number} />
                <button>Submit</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    )
}```
````

Comment: Did you try `SetNumber(null)`?

Comment: Hi Thomas, I tried with setNumber(null), but it is showing the following error:
--> Warning: `value` prop on `input` should not be null. Consider using an empty string to clear the component or `undefined` for uncontrolled components.
--> Warning: A component is changing a controlled input of type number to be uncontrolled. Input elements should not switch from controlled to uncontrolled (or vice versa). Decide between using a controlled or uncontrolled input element for the lifetime of the component.

Comment: Then don't set the `input`'s value to `null`: `<input … value={number === null ? '' : number} />`

Answer (score 0):

Use placeholder instead:

```
const [number,setNumber] = useState(null)

<input 
  type="number" 
  onChange={() => setNumber(this.value)} 
  value={number || ''} 
  placeholder="0" />
```

It will do:

- Display 0 on input field as placeholder.
- The initial value is empty.
- When user types in, the number value gets displayed.

Comment: But what if the value `0` is meaningful? Setting it as a placeholder means that the user will need to manually type 0..

Comment: You're right. But in case of OP, it's not the case. If it was, OP wouldn't try to reset.

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve this is to change the input type to "text" and use the [validator](https://www.npmjs.com/package/validator) library to validate input using onChange event:

```
import validator from 'validator';
...
<input
    type='text'
    value={qty}
    onChange={e => {
        setQty(e.target.value);
        if (validator.isNumeric(e.target.value)) {
            setQty(e.target.value);
        } else {
            setQty('');                            }
    }} />
```